# Is it possible to Export(server-side) javascript chart using JSP in FusionCharts?

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

In my Tomcat container I have created a JSP page in which I'm rendering a chart using pure JavaScript.

Now I want to export this JavaScript rendered chart using server side exporting technology like fusionchart. I have all required jar files in my Tomcat container for this exporting feature in Java EE (FCExporter.jar, etc).

Comment: Why not you get all charts in one hidden control and read it in server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the Answer.
I have created the Servlet and passing request to that servlet in tomcat container from JS..

```
<"chart exportEnabled="1" exportAction="Save" exportAtClient="0" 
    html5ExportHandler="http://localhost:8085/FusionCharts_J2EE/JSP/ExportExample/IMGExporter" 
    caption="Brand Winner" yAxisName="Brand Value ($ m)" 
    xAxisName="Brand" bgColor="F1F1F1" showValues="0" canvasBorderThickness="1" 
    canvasBorderColor="999999" plotFillAngle="330" plotBorderColor="999999" 
    showAlternateVGridColor="1" divLineAlpha="0">
```

and in servlet ..I got the svg parameter.with

```
request.getparameter("svg");
```

and with following command i have generated the jpeg of fusion chart..

```
java -jar batik-rasterizer.jar -d D:\ -m image/jpeg samples/out.svg
```

hurray....

Comment: Using this method, you would still have to render the chart in a page before you can get the svg right?

Comment: @Ryan..yes ..the chart should be fully loaded in a page after that you chould click on export..so proper svg format is generate for that chart..

Comment: Hmm I see. Do you know if there is a way to get a filename parameter that was specified in the xml? I was trying to find a list of parameters you could get from the exportChart function in FusionCharts but had no luck.

Comment: @Ryan..which filename parameter??are you talking about this to get in ??html5ExportHandler??

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out: `request.getParameter("filename")`. I was talking about the parameters passed to the servlet. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with some tweaking.

Please read: http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?exporting-image/ECPureJS.html#ownserver

[section: Setup your own server to process and export JavaScript charts ]

This tells you how to set up your own server for server side export of JS charts.

Well, you need to have php running in your server and download the batik jar as stated in the steps listed in the above page.

Once setup, edit the index.php (of the export) file to save the generated image to your server location.

In case you do not have php, you need to write Java EE code to do the same work done by index.php

OR

[added after a while]

If you wish not to use any client side rendering, rather do a silent server-side creation of chart images, you can follow http://fcimg.org/

Comment: I dont want to add php..and even i don't understand php..can you please guide how to convert that code in J2EE???